# How can I set default location in google maps addMarker with GPS turned off?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, location

I am doing a project that needs a to be marked in google maps. If I turn off my GPS I cannot set my default marked location in my maps.  But when I turn on my GPS I can see my default location. Is it possible even thou my GPS is turned OFF I can set a default marked location???

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add `Marker` to the `GoogleMap`. This approach of course depends on that you have some last location of user. You can try to get last location with both `LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation` `NETWORK_PROVIDER` and `GPS_PROVIDER` and then create `LatLng` from that information.

```
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),
            location.getLongitude());
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
```